# Statistical Genetics - How to interpret data & analysis

Tags: generalized-linear-model, biostatistics, bioinformatics, genetics, medicine

My question is how to interpret $G_{ij}$ in the following statistical genetic model $$h(\mu_i) = \alpha_0 + \alpha'X_i + \beta'G_i,$$

where $G_i = (G_{i1},\dots ,G_{im})$ are allele counts (zero, one, or two variant alleles) for $m$ variants of interest (from page 10 of this paper: [link](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4085641/)).

Specifically, I am wondering

- if the DNA sequence is what is read (please correct me if this is wrong), then how is the allele type and count determined from the sequence?
- if each of the $m$ variants correspond to separate and disjoint regions of the genome?
- since genes consist of DNA, and there are a very large number of possible DNA sequences why are there only 0, 1, or 2 alleles?

Please feel free to respond to only as many of these points as you are able or willing. Also, I understand that these questions may reflect my misunderstanding of the context and therefore be difficult to answer.

I would appreciate any input - thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I think that this has more to do with definitions in genetics rather than with the statistical issues that we address on this site. I'd recommend asking instead on https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com or on https://biology.stackexchange.com/ . If you do ask elsewhere, please help us keep this site organized by deleting your question here.

Comment: Gotcha - I decided to post here on the basis that it is a statistical model (from a paper written by biostatisticians), so hopefully more people here might be familiar with it. However, if not, I will certainly remove it if I end up posting elsewhere.

Comment: [This Biology Stack Exchange page](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/13766/16326) might be a good place to start. I'd recommend reading that page and its links, then posing a question on that site specific to the parts of your question that are still unanswered.

Comment: [This Bioinformatics Stack Exchange page](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/17720/10035) might also be helpful. I don't use those sites often enough to know which would be better for you. Double-posting on the Stack Exchange network is frowned upon, so look over the sites and choose the one that seems most helpful. Try searches on both sites for something like "variant allele": https://biology.stackexchange.com/search?q=variant+allele or https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/search?q=variant+allele .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As was raised in the comments your questions are more biology-related than statistical, but I'll make an attempt to address both.

Recall that DNA is essentially a long sequence of nucleotides **A**denine, **C**ytosine, **G**uanine, and **T**hymidine, always pairing up A-T and C-G into two complementary strands. One of the great surprises that came out of sequencing the human genome is that there isn't really a single 'reference' genetic sequence, we all carry tens or hundreds of thousands of polymorphisms that may or may not lead to changes in function (most tend not to).

Let's take a very simple example gene most commonly encoded by **AAG**, which we'll call variant 1. We might also observe people with variants such as **AGG** and **ATG**, making $m=3$ in this toy example. Real genes are much longer & will likely have *many* more variants.

Also recall that the chromosomes that make up our DNA come in pairs: you inherited one copy of each gene from your father and one from your mother (the exception being the sex chromosomes if you're genetically male and some very rare & usually non-viable chromosomal abnormalities). Each of these copies is called an allele, and you can therefore have no, one, or two copies of each sequence variant - and will have exactly two in total of *any* variant. All of this should let you piece together the answers to your questions, which I took a bit out of order in the hope this makes more sense.

To cover the statistical aspect as well, consider having observed the following sequences of our example gene in a few subjects:

| Subject | First allele | Second allele |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **AAG** (variant 1) | **AAG** (variant 1) |
| 2 | **AGG** (variant 2) | **AAG** (variant 1) |
| 3 | **AAG** (variant 1) | **ATG** (variant 3) |
| 4 | **ATG** (variant 3) | **AGG** (variant 2) |

In the design matrix of the statistical model for our particular gene, focusing only on the $G$s and their $m$ subscript, this would become:

| $i$ (subject) | $G_1$ | $G_2$ | $G_3$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

The full design matrix will include an intercept term and possibly other subject-level covariates, there might hypothetically also be subjects that have all $G$s zero (they don't carry any variant of interest).